# Delete old docker images from all kubernetes Node

Tags: docker, kubernetes, garbage-collection

Kubernetes Garbage Collection have a option to delete the images when it reached to a certain percentage of disk usages [Link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/#image-collection)

Is there any way to delete all docker images which is more than three days old and not being used now instead of doing it manually ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps

1. Create a shell script to run docker system prune -f.
2. Build a docker image using the shell script from above
3. Deploy a cronjob to clean up daily or twice in a day

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply connect to the node in question and run `docker system prune -f` there directly.